# The different number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with 10 vertices and vertex degrees from $\delta=2$ to $\Delta=9$. What numbers of edges can $G$ have?

I solved it checking all cases and applying Havel–Hakimi algorithm but it takes one hour !

Comment: You have an implicit question here, but it would help to make it explicit.  You're asking how to answer the given question faster?

Comment: Does the graph need to have vertices of degree $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, and $9$ (i.e., all intermediate values) or do you just need $\delta=2$ and $\Delta=9$ (and some of the intermediate values can be skipped)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta=2$ and $\Delta=9$, then you have one vertex $c$ connected to all other vertices and another vertex $s$ connected to $c$ and one other vertex.  The vertices other than $s$ could form a clique so the maximum number of edges is $36+2=38$.

If you can find a graph with a minimal number of edges, which I believe to be $14$, then by selecting the vertex with degree $2$, you can add any of the edges in the clique to get all values up to $38$.

The minimal example that I'm thinking of is a wheel graph that has $9$ spokes.  Remove $4$ edges around we wheel in an alternating pattern to guarantee that you don't remove the two of the incident edges to any vertex.

$14$ is, indeed, the smallest possible number of edges.  If we were to assume that $9$ of the vertices had degree $2$ and one has degree $9$, by adding up the degrees we get $2\cdot 9+9\cdot 1=27$.  Since the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges, the sum of the degrees must be at least $28$, and half of $28$ is $14$ as in the example above.

Comment: I think this is correct except that the first graph you mention has $36+2$ edges.

Comment: Thank you . How we can guarantee that graphs are between 14 and 38 edges exist ?

Comment: Pick a vertex of degree $2$ and a vertex of degree $9$.  You can add any edge that isn't incident to either of these vertices one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that for any graph $G$ we have:

$\sum _{v\in V(G)}d(v)=2\times E$

where $d(v)$ denotes the degree of vertex $v$ and $E$ is the set of edges in $G$.

Now, there exists a graph on 10 vertices in which every vertex has degree 2 (namely, the cycle graph $C_{10}$). In this case we can use the above formula to get:

$20= 10\times 2 = 2\times E$

so $E=10$ is the minimum number of edges.

We can find the maximum number of edges in a similar way. This time every vertex has degree 9 (i.e. the complete graph $K_{10}$). So:

$90= 10\times 9 = 2\times E$

In this case we have $E=45$.

So there are $45-10+1=36$ possible numbers of edges.